# ¿Cómo puedo guardar el usuario iniciado en mi variable?

Tags: android-studio, json

Estoy haciendo un login para un app y al parecer todo va bien, hice el login, pero al parecer el usuario que inicia sesion no me lo esta guardando en mi variable "UserLog", quisiera saber si alguien puede ayudarme con esto:

Adjunto respuesta del servidor:

```
    {
    "error": false,
    "msg": "Inicio éxitoso",
    "inspector": {
        "id_inspector": 6,
        "usuario": "avilla@gmail.com",
        "id_tipo_usuario": 3
    }
```

Y aqui el metodo de login de mi app de android studio:

```
private void Login(final String usuario, final String clave){
    Isolatot apiInterface = IsolatotClient.getApiClient()
            .create(Isolatot.class);
    Call<Usuario> call = apiInterface.iniciar_sesion(usuario, clave);
    showProgress(true);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Usuario>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Usuario> call, Response<Usuario> response){
            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse:" + response + "Body: " + response.body());//Mostrar respuesta en log
            response.body();
            UserLog = response.body().getUsuario();

            Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Log.e(TAG, "Usuario:" + UserLog);
            showProgress(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Usuario> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Log.i(TAG, "onResponseFail:"+t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Aquí paso una captura del log en el que se ve Usuario: null

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien por si acaso mi clase Usuario.

```
   public class Usuario {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("usuario")
    private String usuario;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("clave")
    private String clave;

    public Usuario(String usuario, String clave){
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.clave = clave;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getClave() {
        return clave;
    }

    public void setClave(String clave) {
        this.clave = clave;
    }
}
```

No se que me faltaria para poder obtener el usuario :/

Gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que veo mas claro es que estas creando mal el objeto java con el que manejaras la data recibida del servidor, con la ayuda de [jsonschema2pojo](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) puedes crear el modelo segun el objeto de respuesta del servidor, empleando esta herramienta segun tu objeto de respuesta, tendriamos lo siguiente:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class Usuario {

    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose
    private Boolean error;
    @SerializedName("msg")
    @Expose
    private String msg;
    @SerializedName("inspector")
    @Expose
    private Inspector inspector;

    public Boolean getError() {
    return error;
    }

    public void setError(Boolean error) {
    this.error = error;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
    }

    public Inspector getInspector() {
    return inspector;
    }

    public void setInspector(Inspector inspector) {
    this.inspector = inspector;
    }

    }
```

y luego para acceder a los datos que estan en el campo "inspector":

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Inspector {

@SerializedName("id_inspector")
@Expose
private Integer idInspector;
@SerializedName("usuario")
@Expose
private String usuario;
@SerializedName("id_tipo_usuario")
@Expose
private Integer idTipoUsuario;

public Integer getIdInspector() {
return idInspector;
}

public void setIdInspector(Integer idInspector) {
this.idInspector = idInspector;
}

public String getUsuario() {
return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
this.usuario = usuario;
}

public Integer getIdTipoUsuario() {
return idTipoUsuario;
}

public void setIdTipoUsuario(Integer idTipoUsuario) {
this.idTipoUsuario = idTipoUsuario;
}

}
```

Bien ahora teniendo nuestras clases que contralaran el manejo de data recibida solo nos queda obtener la informacion asi:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Usuario>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Usuario> call, Response<Usuario> response){
            response.body();
            UserLog = response.body().getInspector().getUsuario();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Usuario> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Esto es porque para acceder a los valores que estan dentro del objeto de respuesta "inspector" es necesario crear un acceso a dicho campo por medio de un modelo como te lo acabo de mostrar.

Comment: Podrias ayudarme con como hacer cuando el usuario no existe? Por que cuando ingreso un usuario inexistente, el app se crashea y se cierra, pero cuando es un usuario correcto, ahi si entra sin problema.

Comment: Para hacer eso tienes que devolver del servidor una lista de objetos usuario, no solo uno, sino todos, y al momento de hacer la petición que te devuelva la lista, recorrerla con un for y verificar si el usuario que ingresaste es igual a alguno de los que existen en la lista que te da el servidor.

Comment: Utilice simplemente el error que me devuelve en la clase "usuario" y ya no se cierra :) muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Excelente!, Que bueno que te sirva amigo  :)